# Explain why it's impossible for the graph with degrees (n-2, n-1, ..., 1,0) when n is greater than or equal to 2 without using sequence algorithms

Tags: graph-theory

It's pretty obvious why it doesn't work using the sequence algorithms.

So the way I thought of it:(n is the number of vertices)

at n = 1: you get 0, which is the graph of just one vertex

at n =2: you get 1, 0 which is two vertices with one having a degree of 1, but the other vertex has no edges so this is impossible.

this continues on for n greater than 2 as well. Not sure if this is enough to answer the question.

Edit: possible new solution, there are n possible degrees for n vertices which is impossible when $n\geq2$

Comment: You mean, why is it impossible for a graph *to exist* with those degrees?

Comment: this is a classic results for simple graphs: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251310/if-n-is-a-natural-number-ge-2-how-do-i-prove-that-any-graph-with-n-vertic