# How to prove that at least two vertices have the same degree in any graph?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I want to prove that at least two vertices have the same degree in any graph (with 2 or more vertices). I do have a few graphs in mind that prove this statement correct, but how would I go about proving it (or disproving it) for ALL graphs?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Symmetric, simple graphs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If n is a natural number ≥2 how do I prove that any graph with n vertices has at least two vertices of the same degree?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251310/if-n-is-a-natural-number-ge-2-how-do-i-prove-that-any-graph-with-n-vertic?rq=1)

Answer (score 20):

Say graph is simple with no loops and that all vertices have different degree $d_1,d_2,...d_n$, then $$\{d_1,d_2,...d_n\} = \{0,1,2...,n-1\}$$

So there is a vertex with degree $n-1$ and a vertex with degree $0$. A contradiction.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to include that the graph is simple?

Comment: Is it necessary to specify "no loops"?

Comment: Of course. Take a graph with two vertices and one connected to it self. @Shufflepants

Comment: @greedoid Then by "no loops" did you mean "no self connection"? Otherwise I'd interpret "simple with no loops" as being equivalent to a tree. But in any case, the OP didn't specify "simple" or "no loops". So, it would seem the answer to the question is: it's not provable because it's not true.

Comment: Because I didn't see it at first: This follows because in a simple graph the degree of any vertex must be less than the number of vertices. Thus if the vertex degrees are all different and less than $n$ they *must* be $\{0, 1, 2..., n-1\}$.

Comment: @Shufflepants: In the terminology I'm familiar with, "graph" implies that there are no self-loops and no duplicate edges. (The term "multigraph" is more general.) I can well believe that some people use a terminology where the term "graph" allows self-loops and duplicate edges; if so, it's quite reasonable to answer the question as-is, while still clarifying the terminology by explicitly restricting it to graphs that do *not* have self-loops or duplicate edges.

Comment: Question to @Aqua: if $G$ is simple there there should not be a vertex of degree $0$, so why did you associate a vertex $v_0$ with a degree $d_1=0$? Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

I assume we're talking about finite graphs.  I'm pretty sure your statement is false for infinite graphs.

Assume that a finite graph $G$ has $n$ vertices.  Then each vertex has a degree between $n-1$ and $0$.  But if any vertex has degree $0$, then no vertex can have degree $n-1$, so it's not possible for the degrees of the graph's vertices to include both $0$ and $n-1$.  Thus, the $n$ vertices of the graph can only have $n-1$ different degrees, so by the pigeonhole principle at least two vertices must have the same degree.

Comment: You are assuming the graph is simple?

Comment: Yes.  That is assumed in the definition of graph that I learned.  I learned to call a graph with loops or multiple edges between vertices a "multigraph."

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Graphs are typically defined as being finite. Infinite graphs are a generalization. I did not know this at the time of the post. I will leave this answer up though in case anyone finds it useful.

Here is a counterexample.

Let $G$ be a graph on the positive integers where there is an edge from $x$ to $y$ if $x < y \le 2x$. Note that we will ignore the direction of the edges. So $2$, for example, is neighbored by $1$, $3$, and $4$.

Let $j$ and $k$ be distinct positive integers. Without loss of generality assume that $j < k$. Note that $deg(j) = j + \lfloor j/2 \rfloor$ and $deg(k) = k + \lfloor k/2 \rfloor$. We have that

$$j < k$$
$$\lfloor j/2 \rfloor \le \lfloor k/2 \rfloor$$
$$j + \lfloor j/2 \rfloor < k + \lfloor k/2 \rfloor$$
$$deg(j) < deg(k)$$
$$deg(j) \neq deg(k)$$

Therefore, no two different vertices will have the same degree. $\square$

Comment: As noted at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory#Definitions, "*V* and *E* are usually taken to be finite, and many of the well-known results are not true (or are rather different) for infinite graphs because many of the arguments fail in the infinite case."

Comment: @ruakh Huh, didn't know that. I edited a disclaimer into my answer.